# TypeScript: Importing a module in a Typescript project?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some static data I am trying create a lookup table for so I have an object in a TS file:

**newTSFile.ts**

```
export declare module FontList { 
   export DEFAULT_DATA: {
       'james': {
           'age': '23'
        },
        'jack': {
           'age': '22'
        }
   }
}
```

then in my main TS file, I am importing as

```
import { FontList } from './newTSFile';

// 
console.log("font list: ", FontList)
```

however, it still can't find the file when compiling with the error: `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module .../FontList` .
Not sure what I am doing wrong here in regards to importing

Comment: What's the intent behind the `export declare module` wrapper? Is there a reason why you don't want to simply `export const DEFAULT_DATA = {...}`?

Comment: during compilation, I get `Could not find a declaration file for module './FontList`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

**newTSFile.ts**

```
export const FontList: { 
       'james': {
           'age': '23'
        },
        'jack': {
           'age': '22'
        }
   }
```

**main TS file**

```
import { FontList } from './newTSFile';
```

Comment: Could you format the answer in a way that makes it easy to read the code. Could you also explain the changes you've made and also explain why it was wrong?